# Science fiction novel with aliens that could read dead people's memories

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book about 40 years ago that I would like to read again.

I can't remember the plot but it had a policeman who needed to get some information from a criminal. Some aliens were involved and they could read the memories of people even if they were dead but only for a short while after death.

Comment: This is very brief, can you not remember anything else about it at all that you could [edit] in? [This guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) has some nice pointers.